# How to mount /dev/kvm in a non-privileged pod?

Tags: kubernetes

My pod needs to access `/dev/kvm` but it cannot run as privileged for security reasons.

How do I do this in Kubernetes?

Answer (score 1):

There is a [device-plugin](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/compute-storage-net/device-plugins/) called [KVM Device Plugin](https://github.com/kubevirt/kubernetes-device-plugins/blob/master/docs/README.kvm.md) that serves exactly for this purpose.

> This software is a kubernetes device plugin that exposes /dev/kvm from
>   the system.