# Simple Docker container cluster deployment system

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-swarm, cluster-manager

I am looking for a "*simple*" deployment system that can manage a cluster of computers.

I have one Docker image (hosted on [DockerHub](https://hub.docker.com)) that will run with different environment parameters in this cluster. For this image I have a docker_compose file that I can start on a machine directly (this works right now).

What I am looking for is a cluster management system to which I can add physical computers (nodes) and then I can issue commands like:

```
$ docker-compose up
```

or

```
$ docker run --device /dev/sda -e ENV1 -e ENV2 image_id
```

And ideally the cluster (manager) schedules it on one available node. All the nodes that I will join in the cluster have the necessary resources to run the container, so I am not interested in a cluster management system that can schedule containers depending on their hardware needs. Also, it doesn't necessarily need to have support for Docker, just to be able to issue the commands remotely on the cluster's nodes. Ideally, this would also an API other than command line that I could talk to.

### What I've tried / looked at

1. [Docker swarm mode](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/) - seemed like the perfect choice, but I hit a dead-end because I use the "--device" parameter, which is [not supported](https://github.com/docker/swarmkit/issues/2682) yet (and it might as well never be).
2. [Docker machine](https://docs.docker.com/machine/overview/)

[image: Docker run image]

- this seems exactly what I want, but it's not supported anymore, so I don't think it's a good choice.

3. [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io) sounds good but seems at first sight like an overkill. Also not sure it can do "--device" so I hesitate in going through learning it and hitting another dead-end.

Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: I believe you are spot on. Both docker swarm and docker machine, on their own, are not a good choice mostly due to their uncertain future. Kubernetes is indeed an overkill and to do simple things, you need complex configuration. Still, I would consider managed kubernetes (like on DigitalOcean for example), purely because there is no other choice (yet... hopefully).

Comment: I need to look closer at Jenkins, Travis, Octopus and others. My need is only indirectly tied to Docker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it comes to **kubernetes** and support for something like `--device` in `docker`, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59291859/11714114) answer should dispel your doubts.

It was widely discussed in [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/5607) thread on github. Although there is no exact `--device` equivalent in kubernetes, it's worth repeating that it's possible to use host devices in your kubernetes `Pods` by enabling [privileged mode](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod/#privileged-mode-for-pod-containers) as suggested in [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/5607#issuecomment-258195005) comment:

> ```
>   containers:
>   - name: foo
>     ...
>     volumeMounts:
>     - mountPath: /dev/snd
>       name: dev-snd
>     securityContext:
>       privileged: true
>   volumes:
>   - name: dev-snd
>     hostPath:
>       path: /dev/snd
> ```

It enables you to mount into your `Pod` any device available on specific node using `hostPath` and providing the divice path such as `/dev/snd` from the above example, enabling you to use soundcard available on the host.

You need to decide however, if running privileged containers is acceptable from security perspective in your particular case.

If you look for more secure way of mounting particular host devices that gives you more granular level of control, take a look at [device plugins](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/compute-storage-net/device-plugins/) e.g. specific ones like the one mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59231393/how-to-mount-dev-kvm-in-a-non-privileged-pod/59254950#59254950) for exposing `/dev/kvm` or [more general one](https://github.com/honkiko/k8s-hostdev-plugin#hostdev-device-plugin-for-kubernetes), allowing you to configure practically any devices under host `/dev` into your **kubernetes** `Pods` through device cgroup.

When you're planning to run and manage your **docker containers** on multiple-node cluster, **Kubernetes** doesn't have to be an overkill, especially if you decide to use a managed solution already suggested by @DannyB in comments. It's worth mentioning that its currently available in offers of all major cloud providers: **GKE** on **GCP**, **EKS** on **AWS** or **AKS** on **Azure**, which also says a lot about its growing popularity.

[Kubernetes](http://kubernetes.io/) is also very scalable and dynamically developing solution, gaining popularity quite fast in recent years, so it's definitely worth of having a closer look at it.

Comment: Thank you! For now the risk of running in privileged mode is acceptable. /dev/kvm is also something that is of interest, so thanks again for pointing out the device plugin for it. I'll give it a shot with Kubernetes.